# Size of Structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Have a look at following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Node
{
  int data;
  struct Node* nxt;
};

int main()
{
    int a = sizeof(struct Node);
    int b = sizeof(int);
    int c = sizeof(int*);

    printf("size of Node: %d\nsize of int: %d\nsize of int*: %d",a,b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

following is output of above code:

```
size of Node: 16
size of int: 4
size of int*: 8
```

my question is size of integer is 4 byte and size of integer pointer is 8 byte. So sum of these 2 should be size of struct. 
But why compiler (GCC) says it occupies 16 bytes?

Comment: because of padding.

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  The answer is padding and alignment.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] about structure padding. C compiler knows that
>   storing unaligned data in RAM may be costly, so it pads your data for
>   you. If you have 5 bytes of data in a structure, it will probably make
>   it 8. Or 16. Or 6. Or whatever it wants. There are extensions like GCC
>   attributes aligned and packed that let you get some control over this
>   process, but they are non-standard. C itself does not define padding
>   attributes, so the right answer is: “I don’t know”

https://hackernoon.com/so-you-think-you-know-c-8d4e2cd6f6a6